# QGIS Yellow polygons - 'Control A' turns polygons yellow - how do I deselect?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have added several polygons and hit 'control A' - now the polygons have turned yellow and have red X's.

How do I return my polygons back to their original colour?

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+A is keyboard shortcut to select all features in an active vector layer. The default highlight colour for selected features is yellow. If the layer is in edit mode, you will also see red x's marking the geometry vertices.

To remove the selection you can simply click the toolbar button to deselect features from all layers:

[image]

Or expand the tool button menu to deselect features from the current active layer:

[image]

As you can see, both these actions have keyboard shortcuts.

> Deselect features from all layers (Ctrl+Alt+A)
>
> Deselect features from the current active layer (Ctrl+Shift+A)

If you have the Select Feature(s) map tool activated, you can just click anywhere on the map canvas outside of a feature to deselect all features from the active layer.

[image]

Or run the following in the Python console to deselect all features from an active vector layer:

```py
iface.activeLayer().selectByIds([])
```

To deselect features from all vector layers in your project:

```py
for l in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if l.type() == QgsMapLayerType.VectorLayer:
        l.selectByIds([])
```

Comment: What is the toolbar in the right part of your sreenshot (green arrows upon yellows boxes, green screwdriver and hammer)? I have never seen it before

Comment: @KVO, it is toolbar of QField Sync plugin with actions to package, synchronise and configure projects for QField.